# Converting a docker-compose file to a build and run command

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I would like to start my docker container by using a docker build and docker run command instead of via a compose file.

I started to convert the compose file to commands but I got stuck.

Compose file:

```yaml
version: '2' 
services:
  node:
    build: ./node_js
    command: node server.js
    depends_on:
      - mongo
    links:
      - mongo      
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: development  
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
    volumes:
      - ./node_js:/home/app/chat
      - /home/app/chat/node_modules


  mongo:
    build: ./mongo
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
```

This is what I have come up with so far

Build command (this works when I run it):

```
docker build --tag testenvironment/node_js ./node_js
```

Run command:

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 --link mongoDB:testenvironment/mongo --name nodejs -d testenvironment/mongo node server.js
```

I have replaced the VOLUMES to the dockerfile as following:

```
FROM node:4.3.2

RUN useradd --user-group --create-home --shell /bin/false app &&\
  npm install --global npm@3.7.5

ENV HOME=/home/app

COPY package.json npm-shrinkwrap.json $HOME/chat/
RUN chown -R app:app $HOME/*

USER app
WORKDIR $HOME/chat
RUN npm install

VOLUME ./node_js:/home/app/chat
VOLUME /home/app/chat/node_modules

CMD ["node", "index.js"]
```

I though this was everything but when I run the command Node.js starts and stops immediately. Can somebody tell me what I did wrong or what I missed.

If you would like some more info please ask.

Thanks in advance!

I think I found a fix. While looking around in kinematic I found a UI for the containers volumes and it didn't show a local folder, so I added it manually.

Does this mean the command for mounting the volume is incorrect?

Final docker run command I used:

```
docker run --network mongo_node_network -p 8080:8080 -e NODE_ENV=development -v //c/path/to/node_js:/home/app/chat -v /home/app/chat/node_modules --name node_js -d testenvironment/node_js  node index.js
```

When I manually add the volume using the Kinematic interface it works fine.
Docker inspect result:

```
"Mounts": [
        {
            "Type": "bind",
            "Source": "/c/Users/Jan/Desktop/PrototypeEnvironment/Software/PrototypeEnvironment/TestEnvironmentBuildTest/node_js",
            "Destination": "/home/app/chat",
            "Mode": "",
            "RW": true,
            "Propagation": ""
        },
        {
            "Type": "bind",
            "Source": "/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/volumes/df707fea2364811c9377276e8fdbbd16d9af55720475f436b6206e77806bdb50/_data",
            "Destination": "/home/app/chat/node_modules",
            "Mode": "",
            "RW": true,
            "Propagation": ""
        }
    ],
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix the image name and use network instead of the link. This is roughly equivalent to your docker-compose:

```
docker network create mynet

docker build -t testenvironment/node_js ./nodejs
docker build -t testenvironment/mongo ./mongo

docker run -d --network mynet -p 27017:27017 --name mongo testenvironment/mongo
docker run --network mynet -p 8080:8080 -e NODE_ENV=development -v $(pwd)/node_js:/home/app/chat --name nodejs -d testenvironment/node_js  node server.js
```

Remove the `VOLUME`s you've added in the Dockerfile.

As @BMitch suggests, *Since you're on D4W, make sure the directory you are mounting is on a drive that's shared with the Docker VM. The menus for Docker toolbox may be different from these [docs](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/#shared-drives):*
[image]

Comment: Thank you @Robert for your anwser, it has helped a lot, but I'm its still not quite working. I have made some changes to your docker run command for Node.js: 1. I used an absolute path instead of  $(pwd) because it didn't work (I think it has someting to to with me using Docker toolbox for windows). 2. I added the second volume, I think you only added one (am I right?). But when I start the nodejs container I get the following error: `Error: Cannot find module '/home/app/chat/server.js'`.

Comment: The run command I used: `docker run --network mynet -p 8080:8080 -e NODE_ENV=development -v /home/app/chat/node_modules -v //c/path/to/node_js:/home/app/chat --name node_js -d testenvironment/node_js  node server.js`

Comment: Does your volume source exist inside your windows' home dir? I believe that it's not permited by default otherwise

Comment: It is, is there a fix for this?

Comment: Is index.js or server.js what you have? Try the run with index.js

Comment: Resulted with the same type of error: `Error: Cannot find module '/home/app/chat/index.js`

Comment: Change node inde.js to `ls -l`. See whether the volume is mounted

Comment: Since you're on D4W, make sure the directory you are mounting is on a drive that's shared with the Docker VM. The menus for docker toolbox may be different from these docs: https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/#shared-drives

Comment: @Robert changing the command to `ls -l` gave me the following output: `total 12
drwxr-xr-x 351 app app 12288 Jun 20 06:47 node_modules`

Comment: @Robert & @BMitch I think the directory is already shared, because when I use `docker-compose up` it does work.

Comment: Try with 3 slashes before C drive: `-v ///c/path/to/node_js:.......`. The problem is how to write the source volume dir. You can see it with `docker inspect <container-id>` for the container that does work

Comment: @Robert, 3 slashes gave the exact same result. I used `docker inspect` to check the mounts after I added the volume manually using kinematic. Please see the updated question.